# how to test a setter in c# ?and why?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, setter

I am getting started with c#. I am asked to do an assignement that contains writing a unit test for a setter and checking its output. I don't follow the meaning of testing something very trivial that does not contain any logic. here's the example (SetKeywords() is the method to be tested):

```
public struct Keyword
{
    private string keyword;
    private KeywordTypes type;

    public Keyword(string keyword, KeywordTypes Type = 
    KeywordTypes.String)
    {
        this.keyword = keyword;
        this.type = Type;  
    }

    public string GetString()
    {
        return this.keyword;
    }

    public KeywordTypes WhichType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }
}

public class ShopParser
{
    private Keyword[] keywords = new Keyword[0];

    public void **SetKeywords**(Keyword[] tags)
    {
        keywords = tags;
    }
}
    public Keyword[] GetKeywords()
    {
            return this.keywords;
    } 
    public static KeywordPair[] ExtractFromTaG(ShopParser parser, string 
    serializedInput)
    {
            var findings = new KeywordPair[0];
            foreach (var keyword in parser.GetKeywords())
            {
                var start = serializedInput.IndexOf(keyword.GetStart());

                // Check if keyword is in input string, if not continue 
                with next keyword.

                if (start <= -1) continue;

                var end = serializedInput.LastIndexOf(keyword.GetEnd());

                // Extract the thing between the tags. Tag excluded
                start += keyword.GetStart().Length;

                var substring = serializedInput.Substring(start, end - 
                start);

                // Add substring to result list

                var tmp = new KeywordPair[findings.Length + 1];
                var i = 0;
                for (; i < findings.Length; ++i)
                {
                    tmp[i] = findings[i];
                }
                tmp[i] = new KeywordPair(keyword, substring);
                findings = tmp;
            }
            return findings;
    }

}
```

Comment: And regarding your remark about it being trivial: Regardless of how trivial it is, if it is broken, your app will have a bug. If it won't have a bug, then it's not trivial but dead code and should be thrown away. The best code is code that doesn't exist because it will never break.

Comment: Lastly this is a method and not a setter. In c# a setter is the `set` part of a property such as `int Age { set; }`. Hope that helps.

Comment: The general rule should be that testing trivial things should be a trivial thing to do. In other words, implementing a unit test that tests something trivial, should be a trivial task. As such, you should have a really good reason not to do it.

Comment: And "does not contain any logic", I assume by this you mean "does not do anything useful", because if it does, it *does* contain logic. It might not contain any if-statements, loops, or other such things, but what if I rewrote that method and somehow made it do nothing. Is that OK? If it is trivial to write a unit test that tests that it does the basic thing it is expected to do, what is the problem with that?

Comment: @CodingYoshi I have added more to parsershop class code. My understanding is that setkeyword() is a setter used to set the private Keyword[]. Same for the method that follows it getkeywords() that returns the private Keyword[].

Comment: To test it: Call `SetKeywords` and pass it an array with a few items. Then call `GetKeywords` and assert it returns the exact items.

Comment: However in c# it would be more natural to use a property like `public Keyword[] Keywords { get; set; }`. But you don't have to.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I understand what you're saying, but still can't imagine how I should test this method.

Comment: Question #1 you should always be asking yourself when you're thinking of testing something is: How can I observe the effect of this code. So, how can you observe the effect of calling this method? Can you check that a property was changed to a specific value, that you called the method with?

Comment: I hope the `GetKeywords()` is within your `ShopParser` class because right now it is not but I assume that's just a typo. Also, note that users can call `GetKeywords` and change the items, something to keep in mind.

Comment: Maybe you have a java background because your code is very java-ish. Just an observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to test?**

When you call `SetKeywords`, it should do something. Right now it sets the internal array `keywords`. So the question you need to ask yourself is how can you be sure it did that? Well you have a `GetKeywords` method which returns the internal array so we can use that to conduct our tests as below:

```
[TestClass]
public class ShopParserTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SetKeyWords__WhenGivenAnArray__MustSetTheInternalArray()
    {
        // Arrange
        var k1 = new Keyword("One", KeywordTypes.String);
        var k2 = new Keyword("Two");
        var parser = new ShopParser();
        var keys = new Keyword[] { k1, k2 };

        // Act
        parser.SetKeywords(keys);

        // Assert
        Keyword[] keysReturned = parser.GetKeywords();
        Assert.AreEqual(keysReturned[0].GetString(), k1.GetString());
        Assert.AreEqual(keysReturned[0].WhichType(), k1.WhichType());
        Assert.AreEqual(keysReturned[1].GetString(), k2.GetString());
        Assert.AreEqual(keysReturned[1].WhichType(), k2.WhichType());

        // More tests
    }
}
```

**Some Suggestions**

Keep in mind that you may need to write a lot more tests based on your requirements. For example, what if the user does this:

```
Keyword[] keysReturned = parser.GetKeywords();
keys[0] = new Keyword();
```

Do you want to allow that?

Also, in C# your classes can be simplified and take advantage of properties. So your `Keyword` and ShopParser classes be written like this:

```
public struct Keyword
{
    public Keyword(string keyword, KeywordTypes type =
    KeywordTypes.String)
    {
        this.TheKeyword = keyword;
        this.KeyType= type;
    }

    public string TheKeyword { get; private set; }
    public KeywordTypes KeyType { get; private set; }
}

public class ShopParser
{
    public void SetKeywords(Keyword[] tags)
    {
        this.KeyWords = tags;
    }

    public Keyword[] KeyWords { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lack of complex code does not mean there are no design decisions by the author of the class that should be verified and protected by unit tests. I.e. the fact you picked value type for items in the collection makes some behaviors impossible and some trivial - the test are there to clarify that class implements that *design decision* properly and protects *the behavior* of the class in case of future modifications.

Unit tests for setters for properties of a collection type (unlike value type `int`) are actually *non trivial* because one must verify that contract of the class is defined and properly supported - does setter make a copy of a collection or reference existing one, does it make deep or shallow copy? Testing each of the cases properly is definitely not a trivial task. (Same to lesser extent applies to all reference type properties, but in non-collection cases expectations of behavior are usually more aligned with default).

So what you want to do *before* writing the test is to decide the behavior of your collection property - does it make copy at the moment of setting or refers to the original live instance. If collection would be of reference type (not the case in the question) you also need to decide if it takes shallow or deep copy (deep copy is unusual).

After you made the decision it is somewhat trivial to write the test to verify. You add following tests:

- is the collection exposed via getter has the same items in the same order as one used to call setter (applies to both copy and reference approaches)
- use setter with a  collection and modify original collection (in case of an array change items in the collection). Verify that the collection exposed by the getter behaves properly (either matches updated one for live reference or stays the same for copied one)
- if using collection of non-immutable reference types verify that modifying individual items behave as expected (either reflects modification for non-deep copy or stays the same)
- if collection just refers to original one tests *may* be shortened to just checking for reference equality between the original and value returned by the getter, but doing so will not *document* expected behavior and limit ability to modify in the future.

One may need additional test to validate that collection returned as result of the getter behaves as designed by the class author - in particular if modification of the resulting collection are reflected in the class' state or not (getter returning shallow/deep copy of the state or just exposing internal state directly as shown in the question).

Please note that it is discouraged to have setters for collection properties - see [CA2227: Collection properties should be read only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2227?view=vs-2019). So code in the question sort of follows the recommendation but better name like "AddKeywords"/"ReplaceKeywords" would clarify behavior rather than general "set".